# running a bunch of SQL files in a folder

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a bunch of scripts in a folder which I have to run **in order**. I just open it up in SSMS and hit execute one by one. I have to wait for one of them to complete then run the second one.

Is there a way for me to create a batch script or a script in SSMS (if its possible) that will go through the files one by one? This would save me time as I can do something else while the scripts are running and prevent error (most of them rely on temp tables created in succession).

I think a batch script with `sqlcmd` is what I am looking for but no idea how to accomplish this task.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy to put together a batch file for this. Put something like the following into a text file but end the file with .bat, eg 'ExecuteMyScripts.bat'

Sqlcmd takes various arguments but the main ones are -S for server instance, -d for database, -i for input file ie your SQL file, -U for user, -P for password, and -o for output file. Watch the case of the letters.

So open notepad and add the following:

```
sqlcmd -S mysqlserver -d mydb -U sa -P pass1 -i "c:\script1.sql" -o "c:\script1log.txt"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :eof
sqlcmd -S mysqlserver -d mydb -U sa -P pass1 -i "c:\script2.sql" -o "c:\script2log.txt"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :eof
sqlcmd -S mysqlserver -d mydb -U sa -P pass1 -i "c:\scripr3.sql" -o "c:\script3log.txt"
```

Save the file as ExecuteMyScripts.bat.
Double click the file and both script will be executed.

Adding 'IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :eof' after each sqlcmd call will jump to the end of the script if error found.

Full usage found here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Looks like the -b option: -b (terminate batch job if there is an error)

Comment: Ps I've made the assumption your list of files is static.

Comment: Thankyou, is there a way to get all the messages on the screen one by one (i have a bunch of select msg="updating this now..."). 

it shows up on the log file but I want it to display on the screen. `-e` dosn't work.

Comment: PowerShell will let you do this not sure msdos will thou http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/39af0bba-8d5d-40cf-963d-ff4e9855925f